# Stop a loop while xpath = no such element

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to stop a while loop when an xpath is not displayed. However, the code stop with a `NoSuchElementException`message instead.  Here is my code,

```
 n=1
    while n<100:


        n+=1
        time.sleep(10)

#       

        Data=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//tbody//tr//td//span//a[text() != ""]').is_displayed()

        if Data == True:

           ...

       if Data == False: 
           break
```

But I obtain:

> "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//tbody//tr//td//span//a[text() !=
>   ""]"}"

And this is exactly when I want to stop the loop... when the element is not locatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `try` block and import the exception from `selenium`.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

...

while n<100:

   ...

   try:
        Data=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//tbody//tr//td//span//a[text() != ""]').is_displayed()
   except NoSuchElementException:
        break

   ... rest of code ...
```